# r sandwich standard errors with felm (lfe) regression: dynamically defining the formula

Tags: r, regression

I using the felm funcion of the lfe package to run a regression with many fixed effects, and I need to use the sandwich package to estimate the standard errors. The formula used in the regression is built dynamically, and I save it in a variable "form". When I call the sandwich functions, it does not understand the model with the formula saved in a variable.

Here is a simple example:

```
# gen process
set.seed(42)
nn = 10
n1 = 3

x <- rnorm(nn)
f1 <- sample(n1, length(x), replace=TRUE)
y <- 2.13*x + cos(f1) + rnorm(length(x), sd=0.5)

# sandwich working
est <- lfe::felm(y ~ x | f1)
summary(est)
sandwich::vcovPL(est)

# sandwich not working
form <- as.formula("y ~ x | f1")
est <- lfe::felm(form)
summary(est)
sandwich::vcovPL(est)
```

Eventhough the results of the regressions are the same, in the second case I can not use the sandwich function, and this last line gives an error that reads: Error: object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable

Any clue on how I can fix this?

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update

On exactly why the second version of the call doesn't work: it has to do with `model.matrix` which doesn't work (I've no solution sorry). Be careful though with the compatibility between `lfe` and `sandwich`, as highlighted in my first answer below.

---

There are two things. First, (I think but to be confirmed) `felm` objects seem not directly compatible with `sandwich` variances, leading to erroneous results. Second, the are many details involved in computing the standard-errors, notably the decision regarding the degrees of freedom to consider -- this is the main cause of differences across software.

Here is an example of how to (almost) obtain the `felm` VCOV with `sandwich`:

```r
base = iris
names(base) = c("y", "x1", "x2", "x3", "species")
 
library(lfe) ; library(sandwich)
 
est_felm = felm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 | species | 0 | species, base)

# vcovCL does not work appropriately when applied to felm objects
vcov(est_felm) / vcovCL(est_felm, cluster = base$species)
#>           x1        x2        x3
#> x1 0.1126600 0.1011106 0.7028052
#> x2 0.1011106 0.1074147 0.1702584
#> x3 0.7028052 0.1702584 0.2571940
 
# Equivalent lm estimation
est_lm = lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + species, base)

# Now: almost equivalence. They are proportional.
vcov(est_felm) / vcovCL(est_lm, cluster = base$species)[2:4, 2:4]
#>           x1        x2        x3
#> x1 0.9863014 0.9863014 0.9863014
#> x2 0.9863014 0.9863014 0.9863014
#> x3 0.9863014 0.9863014 0.9863014
```

As you can see, you need to first estimate a `lm` model, then compute the clustered VCOV with `sandwich`. You end up with VCOVs which are proportional, they only differ in the small sample adjustment.

If you want to have several SEs for a single model, you can have a look at an alternative package to perform OLS and GLM estimations with multiple FEs: [fixest](https://cran.r-project.org/package=fixest).

#### Using fixest

The package `fixest` is compatible with `sandwich`. Here's an example of equivalences:

```r
library(fixest)

est_feols = feols(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 | species, base)

# feols automatically clusters the SEs
# => proportional VCOVs
vcov(est_feols) / vcovCL(est_feols, cluster = base$species)
#>          x1       x2       x3
#> x1 1.020548 1.020548 1.020548
#> x2 1.020548 1.020548 1.020548
#> x3 1.020548 1.020548 1.020548

# Equivalences -- I:
vcov(est_feols, dof = dof(fixef.K = "none")) / vcovCL(est_feols, cluster = base$species,
                                                      type = "HC1")
#>    x1 x2 x3
#> x1  1  1  1
#> x2  1  1  1
#> x3  1  1  1 

# Equivalences -- II:
vcov(est_feols, dof = dof(adj = FALSE)) / vcovCL(est_feols, cluster = base$species)
#>    x1 x2 x3
#> x1  1  1  1
#> x2  1  1  1
#> x3  1  1  1
```

For details on how SEs are computed in `fixest` and how to obtain equivalent SEs from alternative software, please have a look at this vignette: [On standard-errors](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fixest/vignettes/standard_errors.html).